# call a method on form submit with list of arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am catching event of form submit and adding divs to the DOM, code http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/7rkX4/7/
now i want to pass some arguments to the function like name of the commenter, time comment was added etc. I want it to be something like this.

**html**

```
<form onsubmit="addComment('john deo','post_id')">
    <input ......>
    <input ......>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
function addComment(commenter_name,post_id){
  perform operation....
}
```

Comment: question is, i am trying to do this way from last 3 hours, but couldnt achieve it. can you make it

Comment: then what is the alternative to it..

Comment: Pass `this` as an argument to that function... take it from there.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil it would be nice if you could solve this, you have helped me a lot. you can find my facebook profile here in stackoverflow profile

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works fine. The reason it would not work in jsfiddle is because your functions are declared in a `document.ready` type of block by default (see the `onLoad` in the drop down on the left?)

The proper way to bind event handlers would be to bind them in javascript. This would avoid the scope problem.

If you need to get an inline event handler working, you can explicitly define your function as global:

```
window.addComment = function (commenter_name,post_id){
    perform operation....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the name of the commenter in html for example.

Try this (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rkX4/8/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="post">
  <ul class="comments"></ul>

  <div class="comment_entry">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Neha" />
      <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Leave comment" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <ul class="comments"></ul>

  <div class="comment_entry">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Danil" />
      <input type="text"  name="comment" placeholder="Leave comment" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.comment_entry form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $('input[name="name"]', this).val();
    var comment = $('input[name="comment"]', this).val();

    $(this).parent().prev().append('<li><a class="commenter_name" href="/">' + name + '</a><br />' + comment + '</li>');
  });
});​
```

Comment: i think this is fine...i mean it is achieving my needs but its not in a way i wanted, BTW thanks for your long help. you helped me a lot today. you can add me on FB if you want. check my stackoverflow profile. thanks

Answer (score -3):

If I understand correctly you want to add some variable-value pairs to the form on submit. Why not add some input fields to your form with `type="hidden"`, then you can modify their values in your javascript code as you like.